# Ajax queue Backbone js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am running Backbone js 0.9.2 on Rails 3.2.2,I have a page for adding cost rows.A cost have 3 TextFields: title, description and price.

I am saving each cost on blur.

`model.save()` gets called multiple times with very short intervals. Which issues one `create(post)` request then one `update(put)` request shortly there after. The problem I am experiencing is that PUT request sometimes reaches the server before the POST, the result being that model gets created and persisted twice(duplicates).

To save on blur is the requested behavior, so I need a way to queue up requests.
I have read something about Spine js, and that they solve it by some kind of queue. I've also looked in to [this](https://github.com/jbutz/Backbone.Sync.AjaxQueue), but can't seem to figure this out.

It feels like this should be a common issue, working with "single-page-apps" but can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could override the save method and create a queue with a [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) . For example,

```
var MDef = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "/echo/json/?delay=3",

    initialize: function() {
        this.queue = $.Deferred();
        this.queue.resolve();
    },

    save: function(attrs,options) {
        var m = this; 
        console.log("set "+JSON.stringify(attrs));

        // this.queue = this.queue.pipe with jquery<1.8
        this.queue = this.queue.then(function() {
            console.log("request "+JSON.stringify(attrs));
            return Backbone.Model.prototype.save.call(m, attrs, options);
        });            
    }
});

var m = new MDef();
m.save({title: "a title"});
m.save({description: "a description"});
m.save({price: "a price"});
```

And a Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/8nEUm/

Answer (score 3):

User `debounce` from [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle).

> Creates and returns a new debounced version of the passed function that will postpone its execution until after wait milliseconds have elapsed since the last time it was invoked.

This way it will only fire once after the last `blur` event.

Comment: That is not a bullet proof solution, it may solve most cases but there is still a chance that data can be lost.

Comment: @TimBrunsmo, @abraham `debounce` is right. How will data be lost? You *can* replace it with `_.throttle` if you want to force periodic saves.

Comment: @ggozad If a field is focused and user choose to leave page, e.g clicking "next" button, there is a chance that blur event never issues a request. If there is a queue, you can check if queue is finished and then let the user pass along.

Comment: @TimBrunsmo both `throttle` and `debounce` will have the effect you want. They do actually queue the function for later execution.

Comment: @TimBrunsmo unless you are a financial institue you really don't need anything more redundant. A one or two second debounce will almost never get closed before executing.

Comment: I've tried it out and it does not work that well... See, even though I am debouncing, if first CREATE request is not finished next request will be a CREATE too (since model still isNew())and i end upp with duplicates.

Comment: You could ad an extra couple of seconds.