# Deleting from ajax queue backbone

Tags: ajax, jquery, backbone.js, jquery-deferred

I've implemented the backbone ajax queue as mentioned here [Ajax queue Backbone js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10000352/400236)

Now I would like to clear pending queued ajax requests in the pipe. How to do that?

For example:
I've 1 backbone save which has not yet returned from the server and is processing. And one more backbone save is in the queue. Now if a third backbone save call comes, the one in the queue (2nd backbone save) should get removed and ignored. It should not call the server and the third one should get processed once the first backbone save returns.